# Font loading slowly in Rails app. Why is this happening?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a custom font in my `app/assets/fonts`folder but on production, the font is loading slowly leaving buttons blank before the font renders like this:

[image]

and then after 3 seconds, this:

[image]

What is going on? What can I do?

my css looks like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Reckless-Medium';
  src: font-url('Reckless-Medium.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

$reckless-medium: 'Reckless-Medium';
```

and this:

```
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: $reckless-medium;
```

Why does rails make a get request to get the font?

```
Started GET "/assets/Reckless-Medium.otf" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-19 00:53:29 -0400
```

Is the font located on another server?

Answer (score 0):

> Why do rails make a GET request to get the font?

Because you tell it does so. `font-url('Reckless-Medium.otf')` eventually commands client's browser to download the font from your webserver.

> Is the font located on another server?

Not sure. As I see the font you use is custom. I found it on https://befonts.com/reckless-font.html . For fast loading, it could be uploaded on some CDN servers, of Google or CloudFlare for example, and hardlinked to be downloaded from there. But it's too new, so it's doubtful the font is popular enough CDN majors accepted it to their warehouses.

To make fonts (and all static content) to load faster you can move your static files to some CDN service. For example, check https://www.cloudflare.com/ as an option.

Comment: BTW, screenshots from your question show that instead of your custom font browser uses Times New Roman (or something similar). I'd check it